# matplotlib: showing minor tick labels on primary x axis only

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a generic plotting class that uses matplotlib to generate (png) plots that may have multiple y axis, but always a single (shared) x-axis that shows dates.

This is the method that deals with x axis label formatting:

```
def format_xaxis(self, axis, primary):
    steps = (1,2,3,4,6,12)
    step = steps[min(len(self.dates) // 1000, 5)]
    axis.set_axisbelow(True)
    axis.xaxis.grid(b=True, which='minor', color='0.90', linewidth=0.5)
    axis.xaxis.set_minor_locator(MonthLocator(bymonth=range(1,13,step)))
    axis.xaxis.set_major_locator(YearLocator())
    if primary:
        axis.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter(fmt='%b %y'))
        axis.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(DateFormatter(fmt='%b'))
    else:
        plt.setp(axis.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
```

with input:

- primary is a boolean that indicates if this is the primary axis
- axis is a matplotlib axis instance

What I want (and expect from the above method) is that the only the primary axis has labels and that the major labels are month-year and the minor labels month only.

What happens is that only major labels are shown on the primary axis, minor labels are not shown at all.

If I change the last 6 lines to:

```
    axis.xaxis.set_major_locator(YearLocator())
    axis.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter(fmt='%b %y'))
    axis.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(DateFormatter(fmt='%b'))
    if not primary:
        plt.setp(axis.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
```

then minor labels are shown on *all* axes.

**How can I show minor x-axis tick labels on the primary x-axis only?**

EDIT:

Using KevinG's suggestion on the 2nd code block works:

```
    axis.xaxis.set_major_locator(YearLocator())
    axis.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter(fmt='%b %y'))
    axis.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(DateFormatter(fmt='%b'))
    if not primary:
        plt.setp(axis.get_xticklabels(minor=False), visible=False)
        plt.setp(axis.get_xticklabels(minor=True), visible=False)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed that a lot of the tick label stuff has `minor=False` as default arguments.  Without having a multiple axis plot handy right now, I can only suggest you look there.  I imagine something like

```
if primary:
    axis.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter(fmt='%b %y'))
    axis.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(DateFormatter(fmt='%b'))
    plt.setp(axis.get_xticklabels(minor=True), visible=True)
else:
    plt.setp(axis.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
```

should have some effect.

Comment: Thanks KevinG. Your code does not work as is, but your suggestion got me there anyway by applying it to my alternative code (see edit above)

Comment: Glad I could help.  But there's something that irks me about the logic of that solution... it seems that it turns on the minor xaxis labels for all xaxis but the primary... This is fine if all of your xaxis are identical and overlayed (which must be your case!) but will break if you only have one xaxis and it is labelled as primary, or have different positions for each xaxis.

Comment: You are right, all my x-axes are always identical. I have not tested it, but it should also work if there is only a primary axis - in that case the `visible=False` lines don't get executed (which is right).